# How to handle loading multiple images for the purpose of scrolling and zooming? Does DPI of an image affects the way an iPad is going to load it?

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, memory, uiscrollview

I am currently working on an image gallery for iPad. As of now there are about 100 images and the count may increase further. The images I am using are of the resolution 2134x1602 @ 300dpi. Now with ~2.5MB, i have lost the smoothness in scrolling the images to next image. Also I want to zoom the image up to 8X. The images I am using are all PNG type.

The app works fine in the simulator but crashes bad on the device. Instruments show no leaks and no bad allocations too. It must be some Internal memory issue for sure since the gdb reports memory warning while running on the device. I would like to tell you that I am lazily loading the images.

Can anyone help me with this issue and the strategy i should use to get rid of the slow loading and scrolling. Also I'll be glad if you let me know how an iPad's GPU processes the images it wants to load. Also i would like to cite that changing DPI didn't work out well.

Eagerly waiting for some help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is crashing because you are running out of memory.

What you will need to do is scale/tile the images. Have a look at how Google Maps works in a web browser on a normal PC, you will need to do something like this. The screen resolution on the iPad is 1024x768 pixels, so there's no point loading more than that amount of data at any one time. When displaying your image at > 0.5x scale, tile it into sections that are max 1024x1024, pre-scaled. Cache everything to disk. When displaying your image at < 0.5x scale, consider having thumbnails at different resolutions. In between different resolutions, do an alpha blend of two images of different scales: eg for scale 0.75x, do a 50% blend of four tiled scale 0.5x images and one scale 1.0x image.